# Error in getting items in combobox from table

Tags: c#, events

Running the following code, I find that `SelectedIndexChanged` method runs before load method... How can I correct this? I tried resetting the events but that didn't work either

```
namespace adotestquestion 
{
    public partial class Bill : Form
    {
        public Bill()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string constring = "data source=NISHANT-PC ; initial catalog=NIK_DATABASE ; user id=xxxxxx ; password=xxxxxx";
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataSet ds;
        DataTable dt;
        int qty, tax, total, price;

        private void Bill_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select billid from bill", con);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "billid";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "billid";
            MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text);
            int id;
            id = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text);
            con = new SqlConnection(constring);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from bill where billid=@id", con);
            // cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                textBox1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = dr[4].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = dr[3].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = dr[5].ToString();
                textBox6.Text = dr[6].ToString();
                textBox7.Text = dr[7].ToString();
                textBox8.Text = dr[8].ToString();
                textBox9.Text = dr[9].ToString();
                textBox10.Text = dr[10].ToString();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unwire the events subscription in `InitializeComponent` method and wire it at the end of `Form_Load`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to change the events, etc. you can simply check if there is anything in fact selected in the combo box in your event. This will keep the code simple and will work correctly.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        // your existing code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A third alternative is to create a private class-level variable like `isFormLoading` and set it to `true` initially, then set it to `false` at the end of your `Bill_Load` event.

You can check the value of the variable in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` and anywhere else it's needed to determine whether a block of code should run or not.

But really, any of the other provided answers will work.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** whenever you bind an Items to your `Combobox` , `SelectedIndexChanged` event will be fired.

**Solution :** inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` event you need to identify wether it is fired from the `Load` event or due to the Item selection change.

you can declare a `boolean` variable ,set it to `true` whenever control enters into `Load` event.

from `selectedIndexChanged` event only execute the code when `boolean` variable is `false`.

Note : at the end of the `Load` event again change the `boolean` variable to `false` so that `SelectionChanged` event will be fired when actually selection Changes in the `ComboBox`.

Try This:

```
 bool loadevent = false;


private void Bill_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadevent = true;
    con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select billid from bill", con);
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "billid";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "billid";
    MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
    loadevent = false;
}



 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (!loadevent)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text);
    int id;
    id = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text);
    con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from bill where billid=@id", con);
    // cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", id);
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dr[1].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dr[2].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dr[4].ToString();
        textBox4.Text = dr[3].ToString();
        textBox5.Text = dr[5].ToString();
        textBox6.Text = dr[6].ToString();
        textBox7.Text = dr[7].ToString();
        textBox8.Text = dr[8].ToString();
        textBox9.Text = dr[9].ToString();
        textBox10.Text = dr[10].ToString();
    }
 }
}
```